# PHP Remember Me Cookie Issue

Tags: php, cookies

I have a login form with a remember me check box that sets the user email in a cookie that I then want to auto fill in the username the next time they log in. Also, when I use firbug it shows the path of the cookie in the directory where the `login.php` page is. The `index.php` is not in the same directory as the `login.php` directory.

So I have `index.php` page with the login form. When the user submits the form it calls `login.php` which has this piece of code:

```
if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
        if (isset($_POST['remember'])) {
            setcookie("email", $_POST['email'], time() + 9999999);
            $_COOKIE['email'] = $userEmail;
        }
    }
```

and then on the `index.php` code I have this code:

```
$userEmail = $_COOKIE['email'];
```

and then I use the `$userEmail` variable to autofill in the username field like this:

```
<div class="form-group <?php if(isset($userEmail)) { echo $addClass; }?>" >
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Email Address" value="<?php if(isset($userEmail)) { echo $userEmail; } ?>">
</div>
```

I can see that the cookie is being set, but when I try to echo the cookie (email address) it displays nothing.

I know that I am probably not doing this in the best way possible, but it used to work and now it stopped working. Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong?

EDIT: When I use Firebug I see this in the Cookies tab:

- Name: email
- Value: the email address
- Path: this is a different path than the current page i'm on

When I `var_dump($_COOKIE['email'])` it show `NULL`

Comment: stopped working **HOW**? wrong email address entered? no email address? Done any basic debugging, like seeing if the cookie gets set? What value got set in it?

Comment: Sorry, I will update my question, but yes, it sets the cookie with the users email address that was enter when logging in. I can see the cookie is set, but it is not displaying the email address in the input field when I echo the cookie.

Comment: Why do you have `$_COOKIE['email'] = $userEmail;`? If it does anything it is overwriting your value with a non-existent variable.

Comment: @jeroen: that's because PHP won't auto-update $_COOKIE with whatever got set in setcookie()

Comment: @MarcB I know, but `$userEmail` seems to be undefined at that point.

Comment: ah yes. good catch. probably there'd  need to be a `$userEmail = $_POST['email']` somewhere earlier.

Comment: I made some changes based on the comments and again I can see that the cookie is set, but nothing gets outputted

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
        if (isset($_POST['remember'])) {
            setcookie("email", $_POST['email'], time() + 9999999);
            $_COOKIE['email'] = $userEmail;
        }
    }
```

look at the line  `$_COOKIE['email'] = $userEmail;` this should be  `$userEmail = $_COOKIE['email'];` because at that point `$userEmail` hasn't been given a value so you are essentially setting `$_COOKIE['email']` to a null value.

either that or you need to set `$_COOKIE['email'] = $_POST['email'];`

Comment: Sorry this did not change anything

Comment: Either $_POST['email'] is set to a null or empty string value, $userEmail is set to a NULL or empty string the isset() function only checks if the variable in question is defined in the scope of the function call. if you want to check for empty strings. use empty($var)

Comment: So when I remove the redirect from `login.php` and echo the cookie in the login.php page it echos the email address, but once I am on another page it does not echo the cookie

Answer (score 0):

I think :

`if(isset($userEmail))` :

should be :

```
if(isset($userEmail) && !empty($userEmail) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the answers, but this change has fixed the issue. It was setting the path of the cookie to the directory where the `login.php` page was so I had to set the path of the cookie for all directories.

I changed this:

```
if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
    if (isset($_POST['remember'])) {
        setcookie("email", $_POST['email'], time() + 9999999);
        $_COOKIE['email'] = $userEmail;
    }
}
```

to this:

```
if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
        if (isset($_POST['remember'])) {
            $userEmail = $_POST['email'];
            setcookie("email", $userEmail, time() + 9999999, "/");
        }
    }
```

I added `"/"` to the `setcookie`